# How to print at low temperatures (filament melting at about 70 °C)?

Tags: hotend, nozzle, temperature

I'm using Cura to slice prints from a biodegradable polyester called PCL ([Polycaprolactone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycaprolactone)).

I need to print @ ~70 °C but extruder does not run until nozzle reaches 175 °C.

Which setting to change so extruder will turn on when nozzle temperature has reached 70 °C?

Here are my settings for the material:

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: You do not need to use "starting" and "final" printing temperature, only "Printing Temperature" is needed. Can there be a minimum temperature at play here? E.g. usually there are cold extrusion prevention temperatures at play in he firmware, but that doesn't explain that the hot end heats up to 175 °C. Please add the first 30 or so G-code lines.

Comment: Hi oscar, i suspect it is the cold extrusion protection. It is using Marlin. The extruder motor will not turn on until at least 175 °C. How do i disable the cold extrusion setting? Or change the minium temperature from Cura? Or doo i have to install firmware with editted configure? Appreciate it!

Comment: So i looked through the g-code and added in M308 and M17 settings, still nothing. I really have no idea why the extruder is not being turned on. Is there a specific g-code to turn it on? In the code, the e axis is on though

Comment: Please read the [answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/15497) below to disable it. Cold extrusion prevention was the first thing that came to mind. I wondered why the temperature reached over 170, but that was done by you apparently .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

70 °C is a specialty filament. It is well below the `MIN_TEMP` defined in any sane firmware. In Marlin, you **can't** turn on the extruder in any way, while this is online.

You do need to define your firmware to allow such a print - either by dropping the value in the firmware or disabling Mintemp-protection and then *flashing that firmware*. That is quite invasive.

To [temporarily](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M302.html) disable the `MIN_TEMP`, you need to run the G-code `M302 P1` or `M302 S0` - `M302` on its own does nothing. However, some firmware distributions might explicitly prevent these two commands of *turning off* the check.

In that case, you might use `M302 S65` or similar to drop the `MIN_TEMP`.

Comment: Thx, i have added the flags too, still nothing. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JorgeMercent that seems like your firmware bans those two because someone wanted to be smart in writing it. A lower min-Temp is the solution then.

Comment: If one's firmware has no override, an alternative solution without flashing might be wiring an additional resistor to fake the output of the thermistor and shift it up to a range the firmware allows printing at. Depending on if you're more comfortable with software or electronics this could be either easier or harder.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE that's.... tricky and might be dangerous in case you miscalculate: you practically loose temperature control if your resistor is off by half a percent!

Answer (score 3):

In Cura Machine Settings, add `M302 S70`.

Apparently, `M302 P1` and `M302 S0` do nothing, you need to define a non-zero minimum, and in my case, 70. Thanks to 0scar and Trish for your help.