# No extrusion from G-code for cold extrusion application in soldering robot

Tags: extruder, g-code, monoprice-maker-select

My 3D printer is a Monoprice Maker Select v2 and the G-code is being written with VS Code locally and sent with OctoPrint (I have tried directly from the SD as well to no avail).

I have macgyvered the extruder so that it extrudes solder instead of plastic filament for a project. The solder still extrudes using the physical dial on the 3D printer through settings but does not work with through G-code.

I thought this could be from the firmware's cold extrusion prevention, so I played around with the `M302` command. I tried using the `P` parameter and setting the `S` parameter very low as per this [question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/15495/how-to-print-at-low-temperatures-filament-melting-at-about-70-c/15497#15497) suggestions.

It still doesn't work and I'm getting a little frustrated as I do not want to have to change the `conf` and reflash the firmware just for this project.

My code is below. I hope I missed something basic, but whatever it is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
M17 ; enable steppers

M302 S20 ; disable extruder cold safety
M82 ; relative extrusion
G92 E0 ; zero extruded length
G1 F200 E5 ; extrude 5mm

G90 ; absolute positioning
G28 X Y ; home x and y

G0 F10000 ; set feedrate for all following G0 and G1 commands

M300 S0 P100 ; play tone

G0 X100 Y100 ; move to start position
G0 X105 ; move to pos
G0 X100
G0 Y105 
G0 Y100
G0 X110
G0 X100
G0 Y110
G0 Y110
G0 X115
G0 X100
G0 Y115
G0 Y100

G1 F200 E5 ; try extruding again

G28 X Y

M300 S0 P200 ; play end tone

M302 S170 ; reenable extruder cold safety
M84 ; disable all steppers
```
````